# can any one please explain me react setState new to me

Tags: reactjs, setstate

can anyone lemme know the working of each line as i dont have any idea
can we have let in set sate? please explain these 2 lines

```
    const userDetails = previousState.userDetails
    return { userDetails: {...userDetails, [key]: value} }
```

the return in set state i have not understand

```
     this.setState((previousState) => {
     const userDetails = previousState.userDetails
     return { userDetails: {...userDetails, [key]: value} }
     })
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` can accept a function from the previous state to a new state:

```
this.setState(previousState => newState);
```

`previousState => newState` is an arrow function, that will accept the previous state (which will be provided by `setState` when it is invoked), and has to provide the new state.

In the code you posted, the new state is calculated by taking an object from the previous state called `userDetails`, and then appending a new key-value pair to it.

This is done using two mechanisms. The first, is the spread operator: `...userDetails` which adds to the new `userDetails` value all of the key-value pairs that were in the original object. Next, the new value is added:

```
[key]: value
```

This means that a new pair is to be created, where the key is the value of the key variable (I suspect this is available somewhere in the function before the `setState` call), and the value is equal to a variable named `value`, which again is previously available.

This is the notation to use when you want to use a dynamic value as a key in a map.

*Edit - Answering question from comment*

Any function body that is more than one line needs to be put in a block `{ ... }`. When you want to return a value from that function, a `return` keyword is used.

The `return` you see in your `setState` is the return from the function that is passed to `setState`.

Comment: the return m not understanding where is it returning there's no any function ?Can we write return anywhere?the return coming there is confusing as i have not used .how to decide when return be used ?

Comment: Added an explanation